How to configure enabling or disabling of access for non authenticated users?
I have a spring application with using of spring-security. Some of my rest methods are available for non authenticated users. But I'd like to add condition on making them available just for authenticated users if a special field is_enable in data base table has true value. If I save this field with false value those methods are available for everyone again.
My first thoughts were about creating @Service class that will check data base field is_enable value and if user is authenticated. If is_enable is false and user is not authenticated then I'm going to throw Exception.
But I feel that this is definitely not the best solution, and it is not very good to manually call this check method from each rest controller method.
Maybe there is a possibility to add a call to the check method to the WebSecurityConfiguration?
My WebSecurityConfiguration config looks so:
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http.httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests { request ->
            request
                .requestMatchers(
                    EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint(),
                    AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/chat", HttpMethod.POST.name),
                    AntPathRequestMatcher("/v1/chat/**", HttpMethod.GET.name),
                )
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder).jwtAuthenticationConverter(JwtAuthenticationVtbConverter())
}


I suppose for such kind of "custom authentication", you best approach with a custom (security) filter...(to attach it to your security config)

A field is_enabled for what? The URL, the user? That is unclear.

is_enabled is just a feature toggle to close handlers for non authenticated users for some time

The feature you want to look for is @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()"). That annotation is part of Spring Security which is explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html
It's non-trivial to hook this into your your own database, but once you have done this, it is trivial to annotation each Controller method with the rules you want for access.  The syntax can then be more complex like this:
    @PreAuthorize(
        "isAuthenticated() " +
                "&& (hasAuthority('ADMIN') " +
                "|| hasAuthority('SUPERADMIN'))",
    )


I have @PreAuthorize for some handlers. But for other handlers I need this opportunity to turn off in a moment for non authenticated users and an opportunity to turn on it again in a moment without application restart

Then the declarative approach in my answer is not suitable.  You need to inspect the SecurityContext at runtime conditionally
